# Paypal : How to get User's Email Id and Address Details In case of Canceled and Success purchase Product?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway

In my asp.net application I use PayPal Payment get way integration.

In Case of Direct Payment(With out any Login and Registration) Can we get User Email ID and Address Details from PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Website Payments pro DoDirectPayment method, the buyer would be on your site/page when they are entering in their information.  You would just have your page prompt for this information.  If it is passed over to PayPal, this will be listed in the transaction details, as well as IPN.

Comment: In case of Direct Payment buyer will not Enter your information like Email ID, Address all that. when he click on Check out button then the will navigate to pay pal site. when his payment success then i wont his email id and address back from pay pal.

Comment: What PayPal service are you specifically using?

Comment: i am using pay pal express check out .

Comment: So if you are using Express Checkout, you would be making a SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment API calls.  If if the buyer is cancelling out of the flow before they go to PayPal and enter in the information, you wont get this data back.  If they are enter it in and are returned back to your site, but they decide not to complete the transaction from your site, you can use the EC Token with the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call to still get the information as long as they are past the PayPal page and back on your site when they decide to cancel.

Comment: actually i wont only when buyer complete our transaction then i wont back checkout details back from pay pal. i wont to use TransactionSeach Api so if you have any code project so plz Provide me

Comment: You can find some of PayPal's code samples at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples for the different API's.